# While loop is exiting before the end of the file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh

I am reading a file and writing and the while is exiting before reaching the end of file. Always it is existing at n-1. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks details and actual code. Probably it's something like

```
while read variable; do …
```

`read` is able to read an incomplete line, but it returns failure in such case. Therefore the body of the loop is not executed.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195) requires a trailing newline character to consider any line to be complete.

> 3.195 Incomplete Line
> A sequence of one or more non-<newline> characters at the end of the file.
>
> […]
>
> 3.206 Line
> A sequence of zero or more non-<newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character.

The newline character in Unix/Linux is not a line separator. It's a line *terminator*. Because of this convention any text tool may miss an incomplete line.

You can check and fix your input file with a text editor that is aware of the problem, e.g. [`vim`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11628).

Or you can modify your code. The same problem is [solved on our sister site, U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482525/108618):

> ```
> while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
>     printf '%s\n' "$line"
> done <file
> ```
>
> […]
>
> When an incomplete line is read, `read` will fail, but `$line` will still contain data. The extra `-n` test will detect this so that the loop body is allowed to output the incomplete line. In the iteration after that, `read` will fail again and `$line` will be an empty string, thus terminating the loop.